# how to update the credentials for Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, devops, service-principal

I get this issue on my aks cluster

> Your service principal has expired or is invalid. Please check if you
> are using the correct secret or if the key has expired.

[image]

I think the problem is the current service principal needs to be reset because I think it is already expired.

I have followed the instruction in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/update-credentials?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_Health), but am still unable to do it even using the account with owner access

Using Global Administrator user

```sh
root@root~ % SP_ID=$(az aks show --resource-group myclusterk8s --name myclusterk8s \
    --query servicePrincipalProfile.clientId -o tsv)
```

I already get the id from the first command, but when we do the second command the id we get from the first command is cannot be used

```sh
root@root ~ % SP_SECRET=$(az ad sp credential reset --name "$SP_ID" --query
password -o tsv) ERROR: Resource
'6ec95333-4a5f-4sd1-8478-4b367a4b3711' does not exist or one of its
queried reference-property objects are not present.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Resource 'appID' does not exist or one of its queried
> reference-property objects are not present.

The error suggests that the service principal does not exist in your Azure AD

Firstly, you need to check if the service principal exists in your Azure Active Directory

If the service principal does not exist, you can create a new service principal and update the AKS cluster with the new service principal credentials

If the service principal still exists and you are facing the issue, you can create a new client secret in the Azure Portal. Then you can update the AKS cluster with the new credentials